# I did not add @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) in my instrumentation tests

Tags: android-testing

The android's testing documentation and a lot of other tutorials keep saying that I should include this line `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` in all of my instrumentation tests. But, I did not add this annotation in any of my instr. tests and still all of them are running fine. So,

What is happening and Why to add  `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` above instr. test classes?